# the lower part of the login screen is black for some time

Tags: android

[image: Login screen image]

In login screen if I press soft keyboad enter after entering email and password.the lower part of the login screen is black for some time here i am attaching the screenshot please look on it

```
public void loginButtonClickListener(final View view) {
    emailTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
    emailText = emailTextBox.getText().toString().trim();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Lisnx", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("useremail", emailText);
    editor.commit();

    passwordText = passwordTextBox.getText().toString();
    if (emailText == null || emailText.length() == 0) {
        CustomToast.showCustomToast(this,
                Constants.USER_EMAIL_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR,
                Constants.TOAST_VISIBLE_SHORT, layoutInflater);
        emailTextBox.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (passwordText == null || passwordText.length() == 0) {
        CustomToast.showCustomToast(this,
                Constants.PASSWORD_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR,
                Constants.TOAST_VISIBLE_SHORT, layoutInflater);
        passwordTextBox.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    try {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus()
                .getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, null,
            this.getResources().getString(R.string.authenticateUser), true);

    authenticateUser(view);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device (if a real device, which one)? Which Android version? And as @UdiOshi mentioned, please post relevant code.

Comment: Could you please look in to the code.